# Can I use .NET core 3.0 SDK on Microsoft's Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk, botframework

I installed the latest .NET core SDK (3.0.100) and wanted to use it in my Bot Framework project, since I'm adding Entity Framework Core (the latest version requires net core 3). When I change my settings:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

VB2019 tells me `the current .net SDK does not support targeting core 3.0`.

When I check my .NET core SDKs in the CLI `dotnet --list-sdks` I can see the .net 3 sdk installed.

Do I have to keep using netcoreapp2.1 and an older version of Entity Framework Core, or can I upgrade it?

Comment: Did a quick test with the template, and stable package doesn't work with netcore 3, but 4.6.0-preview1 seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# Bot Framework is dependent on .NETStandard 2.0, as seen here:

[image: MS Bot Builder dependencies image]

Because .NETStandard doesn't support 3.0 as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), AFAIK, you won't be able to use 3.0, even if it's installed.  I recommend raising this issue in the [BotBuilder-Dotnet repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet)

Comment: Hey, not sure if Bot Framework works with netcore 3, but netcore 3 supports netstandard 2.1 and previous, as stated in that page you linked.
_The following table lists the minimum platform versions that support each .NET Standard version. That means that later versions of a listed platform also support the corresponding .NET Standard version. For example, .NET Core 2.2 supports .NET Standard 2.0 and earlier._